# Pass value from HTML to Python with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

So I am using Flask as micro framework and in one of my templates I am using the following Table:

```
<table id = "productentabel" width = "auto" class="table table-striped b-t b-b">
<thead>
<tr class = "header">
<th>Name</th>
<th>Url</th>
</thead>
{% for file in all_files['files'] %}
{% if file['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'  %}
<TR>
<TD  width="auto" >{{file['name']}}</TD> 
<td><a class="btn btn-xs white" href = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/{{file['id']}}" target ="_blank">Go to file</a></td>
<td><form method=POST action="delete_file"><input type=submit name="delete" value ="{{file['id']}}" class="btn btn-xs white">Delete file</input>
</form></td>
</TR>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</tr> 
</table>
```

My question is about the following HTML code:

```
<form method=POST action="delete_file"><input type=submit name="delete" value ="{{file['id']}}" class="btn btn-xs white">Delete file</input>
</form>
```

As you can see I am trying to pass a value to my Python code when a click is made on the input. The value is passed to my Python code, but now the value is visible on the front end, so it looks like this:

> 1svpTERHaYd-wSpFBRRRjp1TOj0H-FH4_66H2W1OLY Delete file

But I want it to be like this:

> Delete file

In Python I am doing the following to extract the value:

```
fileid = request.form.get('delete')
```

I also tried something like this:

```
<form method=POST action="delete_file"><input type=submit name="{{file['id']" class="btn btn-xs white">Delete file</input>
    </form>
```

But I don't really know how I then can extract the name in my Python code, because I only need `file['id']` to be passed and the value solution worked for me but that is not the ideal solution.

Comment: BTW.. I think, there is an error in your table structure. you haven't closed the `<tr>` tag inside `<thead>`.

Comment: @Arihant, it's wrongly closed after the loop. While invalid markup, most browsers will auto-close it when they meet`</thead>` tag and ignore the closing tag when they meet it later on. I'm not 100% sure though and it's definitely something that should be fixed.

Comment: @Arihant Ah I see it, thanks.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I thought maybe using CSS could be also a kind of workaround. But I deleted the tag :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `POST` try the `GET` method, like this:

```
<td><form method="get" action="delete_file?file_name={{file['id']}}"><input type="submit" name="delete" value ="Delete file" class="btn btn-xs white"/></td>
```

If you want the `POST` method, you should send the file name via input with the `hidden` type.

```
<td><form method="post" action="delete_file"><input type="submit" name="delete" value ="Delete file" class="btn btn-xs white"/><input type="hidden" name="file_id" value="{{file['id']}}" /></td>
```

In this case you'll get the file id like this:

```
fileid = request.form.get('file_id')
```

BTW: most of your HTML isn't valid, you should really watch a tutorial about it.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your answer and explanation! Care to explain what aspects are incorrect in the HTML code?  I am not really into HTML

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp it's pretty helpful

Comment: You should also read about the deference between `GET` & `POST` http requests

Comment: Thanks for the information, will have a look at it. And I know the difference between both, in this case I needed to use a POST request for what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks for helping :)